# Is "surveillance" adequate for observing a patient in a hospital?

Tags: word-usage

Can this word be used to mean observing the patient's condition in a hospital in order to make a diagnosis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a perfectly legitimate word to use. It is extremely common to say that the patient is to be *kept under surveillance.* The commonest use is in the context of patients with precancerous conditions who are routinely kept under [surveillance](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18656826) for signs of malignant change.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I would normally expect _surveillance_ to be used if the patient is a risk to himself or others – suicide watch or legal custody. I could accept that it's a common medical jargon but would want to see a source backing that up.

Comment: According to my medical connections (who I just asked), surveillance is commonly used in hospitals for patients with acute problems, and especially in areas involving serious mental health concerns. It usually implies a higher level or ongoing observation. I realise this is anecdotal - will try to find a more formal reference.

Comment: surveillance - (http://www.merriam-webster.com/medlineplus/surveillance) - close and continuous observation or testing. It may also refer to long term screening for adverse conditions

Comment: [surveillance](http://www.medilexicon.com/medicaldictionary.php?t=87097) - from MediLexicon "a type of observational study that involves continuous monitoring of disease occurrence within a population."

Comment: For once, I think I agree with just about every answer / comment here! One has to be careful to use a register that won't needlessly create a wrong impression. I can imagine a doctor telling a worried spouse that their spouse's condition is being carefully monitored, then instructing the nurse on the types of surveillance to be carried out.

Comment: Agreed, it sounds like this is legitimate medical jargon then, although not something you'd ordinarily say to patients and loved ones.

Answer (score 8):

'Observation' is my preferred term.  We normally talk of a patient being kept in hospital 'under observation'.

'Surveillance' is not unheard of, but it has a sinister ring about it, and is used in connection with the police and security services, as well as 'CCTV surveillance'! For that reason I would avoid its use in a medical context.

Comment: Yes; English just doesn't behave like we'd want it to. There's nothing sinister connoted by the word 'survey', but 'surveillance' is loaded. Compare 'schematics' and 'scheming'.

Comment: -1 for a wrong answer sorry

Comment: *Surveillance* is certainly used among those in the medical community; a simple web search for *patient kept under surveillance* turns up thousands of examples in research papers. But I agree that lay persons would not ordinarily use it because it has connotations of criminal investigation out of context. We also speak of patients *being monitored*.